# Grabbing key combination for gtkdialog

Tags: linux, user-interface, shell, gtk

Is there any way I can detect combination key event for gtkdialog after pressing a button? I'm after something like this: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-YaHb1xQp1cA/TgCWahD0S4I/AAAAAAAACPM/YKsigh2HAIs/s1600/unity_grab_handles.png
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

i don't know if it helps, but maybe you could try something like this modified:

```
#------------- Accelerators --------------------------------------------------------

#------------- Accelerator Objects ---------------------------------------------
my $accel = Gtk2::AccelGroup->new();
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#------------- Accelerator Shortcuts -------------------------------------------
my ( $key, $mods ) = Gtk2::Accelerator->parse( '<alt>T' );
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#------------- Accelerator connecting ------------------------------------------
$accel->connect($key, $mods, [qw/visible/], sub { ifKeyTranslateGUI($clipboardSearchButton); });
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#------------- Accelerator adding to window ------------------------------------
$mainWindow->add_accel_group ($accel);
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```